# Is it possible to share an iOS clips app via web link in an email?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm looking to create an iOS clip app which I would like to share with my users.

Is it possible to share an iOS clip app via sending the user a link in an email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Apple forum it is not possible to send the link in an email.

> The app clip URL only launches the app clip from one of the mentioned
> invocations. This means that sharing an app clip URL through the Mail
> app doesn't work.

Source - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653607